# Translate Plugin with french as base language

Tags: translation

I have a plugin with french strings, e.g:

```
__('Ordinateur', $this->plugin_slug),
```

Is there a way to let WordPress know that the base language is french?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not good practice. Best thing would be to change all the strings to the english version and then translate it to french. Then you would be up to the standards.

Since I do not have enough reputation points to add a comment, I hereby insert the link to a possible duplicate: [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138243/does-a-translation-i18n-have-to-start-from-an-english-po)